# Restore partitions after CLEAN and MBR2GPT

Tags: windows, restore, mbr

A kind of a disaster has happened with me.

I had to replace Windows 7 with Windows 8.1 on my laptop, which had 3 partitions (size is approximate):
0 100M
1 100G
2 900G

I wrote windows 8.1 to USB and booted from it. But windows installer informed me that this system can't be installed on current disk, because it has MBR table instead of GPT. I found information that MBR can be converted to GPT on the fly without data loosing with MBR2GPT.exe (I thought that this is a part of `disk` command line utility available on installation disk). I found a video where one man shown how to convert MBR to GPT (without any notice that this will delete all partition information from the disk).

Here is the list of commands issued in command line invoked with `shift + F10`

1. diskpart
2. select disk 0
3. clean
4. convert GPT

Then after refreshing the partition list I've realized that clean command removed all partition information without any warning.

I know how to scan the disk for raw data but I would like to avoid that procedure in case it is possible.

Is there any tool which can help me to restore my partition table now?

Comment: MBR2GPT is used when you *don't* wand to lose current partitions. If the disk is empty, you can just convert it to GPT without any additional tool. It doesn't make any sense to clean the disk and then use MRB2GPT on it. Either you didn't properly understand the tutorial, or it's a disastrously wrong one.

Comment: MBR2GPT only exists on Windows 10.  How was this utility used on an incompatible version of Windows?  Those commands had nothing to do with the MBR2GPT utility.  You performed a destructive command.  Data recovery will be very difficult due to your actions

Answer (score 0):

There is [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) util on Hiren's Boot CD (I used HBCD v15.2). It is free and simple.

It has "Analyze" operation. With that operation it found all partitions quickly.

Then I just pressed "write" and all data become available again.

P.S. After recovery I've installed Windows 8.1 in MBR mode on that disk.